# TelephonyManager.getCellLocation() returns null?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, latitude-longitude

I am in a situation in which I have to get Location i.e., Longitude and Latitude through `GSMCellLocation` for this reason am trying the following way:

```
  ...
  TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  location = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
  cid = location.getCid();
  lac = location.getLac();
  ...
```

but application crashes and gives me `NPE`. I have checked it though Logs and debugging, it reveals that `getCellLocation` returns `null` hence I am unable to get `cid` and `lac`. The signature of this method from Google Docs state it this way:

```
Returns the current location of the device. Return null if current location is not available.
```

Now my question is, how can I get current Location before using this method, so that it is not null. Because in my situation I am trying to use this as an alternate of `GPS` and `Network` to get Location. Please update and any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you running it on emulator or device?

Comment: is it possible to print logs

Answer (score 2):

Add this Permission: `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: I have checked, all permissions are added.

Comment: hello i m late here but can u plz explain what is the means of that output like i got [-1,-1,0] when what it is

Comment: @Bhanu Sharma have you find any solution for your problem, if you found let me inform dude

Answer (score 2):

From [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCellLocation()) it could be related to LTE:

> If there is only one radio in the device and that radio has an LTE connection, this method will return null...

Answer (score 1):

getCellLocation() returns null, if current location is not available.please Take a look at

[Telephonymanager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCellLocation%28%29)

Additionally check for the presence of Basebandtype information in your phone settings.

the Following Code is working fine with me You can test that

```
      TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

      int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
      int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
      textGsmCellLocation.setText(cellLocation.toString());
      textCID.setText("gsm cell id: " + String.valueOf(cid));
      textLAC.setText("gsm location area code: " + String.valueOf(lac));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest file I added permissions coarse,fine and read phone state and run on device.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

And now add this code:

```
private void check_ReadPhoneState_Permission() {
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
}

public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.title_location_permission)
                    .setMessage(R.string.text_location_permission)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PhoneDetailsMain.this,
                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PhoneDetailsMain.this,
                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 100: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
        case 200: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
        }
        case 300: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
        }
    }
}
```